# Google Drive API Permissions Insert sendNotificationEmails Bad Request

Tags: permissions, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I'm working with the google-api-php-client Library for Google Drive (LIBVER = "1.0.5-beta") and when I issue this:

```
$permission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
$permission->setType('user');
$permission->setValue($email);
$permission->setRole($role);
$service->permissions->insert($folder_id, $permission, array('sendNotificationEmails'=>false));
```

I get a Bad Request 400 error back.

With all the same settings, if I remove the sendNotificationEmails option, it works fine. The client library does not seem to be doing much more than appending that as a querystring value to the POST request, so could it be a bug in the API?

Comment: Any thoughts from the Google API experts on this one?